# Is it good idea to Sun's implementation of JAXP(jaxp-ri-1.4.2.jar) to AIX?

Tags: jboss, endorsed

We use saaj-impl-1.3.2.jar from Sun.

It requires jaxp-ri-1.4.2.jar from Sun.

Is it good idea to put these Sun's libraries in web application that will work under JBoss on AIX?

Answer (score 0):

Well, why wouldn't that be good idea? A problem with encryption is mentioned in [this thread](http://forums.java.net/jive/thread.jspa?messageID=287978&tstart=0) because IBM JDK doesn't implement all algorithms but there is a workaround (using another algorithm like AES). Apart from this, are you expecting some particular problems?